# Can user application enable mobile data even when they are user disabled?

Tags: root-access, mobile-data, 9.0-pie, background-data

I am trying to localize app that is connecting to the internet even when I have mobile data disabled. 
Is it possible that user installed app (on Android 9) can enable mobile data when they are turned off (probably on background)?

I think that only option is root access / system admin app only. Or device manufacturer preinstalled apps.

Is it possible on standart stock ROM? Does any of Android system privileges have access to such function?

Comment: Have you activated the option Voice over LTE (VoLTE)? In this case it may be possible that the phone opens a data connection even if it is disabled (which would be a bug in my opinion).

Comment: @Robert I have this issue about 4 weeks. Last week I even disabled VoLTE, because I have exactly same thoughts :) 
But it still does not help. 
Thats why I am askting if user installed app can do this, so I can search in installed apps. Otherwise its almsot sure something in the ROM itself.

Comment: I assume your device is not rooted... because user apps with root access on a stock ROM can do this (example: automation apps).